# TwoLineListItem Source Code

Tags: java, android

Since TwoLineListItem has been deprecated as of API 17, I have taken steps to replace it with custom XML and ViewHolder. However, I would really like for my app to look exactly as it had while using TwoLineListItem (since it is a big part of the application). Thus, I would like to know if it's possible to find the XML source code for the most recent TwoLineListItem that Android was using (all the ones I've found have been outdated), or do I have to basically go with trial and error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're searching for. The `TwoLineListItem` is a simple widget which uses a layout that you could easily look at if you search the `layout` folder in the `SDK/platforms/android-x/data/res/layout`. Here is the one for `Jelly Bean`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView android:id="@android:id/text2"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The widget's code is [very simple to replicate](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/TwoLineListItem.java/).

Comment: What you posted is basically what I'm looking for, but it seems to me that this makes the table look slightly different than before, when the TwoLineListItem could be used natively - there seems to be some padding missing from the top and the sides maybe, and the text2 size was not as large as the text1 size.

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with me initializing my array adapter with simple_list_item_2?

Comment: Yes this is possible. The simple_list_item_2.xml is different. You can find it here platforms/android-17/data/res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml

Comment: @JohnRoberts: The [current source code for `TwoLineListItem` can be found online](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/TwoLineListItem.java). It has no layout XML resource. It *is* a `RelativeLayout`. Your formatting is not coming from `TwoLineListItem`, but rather the layout you are supplying to your adapter that uses `TwoLineListItem`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your answer. If there is no XML for TwoLineListItem, then what is the code that is available in the layout folder for TwoLineListItem for?

Comment: @JohnRoberts: It is there for the same reason lots of those layouts are there: because somebody in 2008 thought it was useful and put it in the SDK. It's conceivable that it was even used back in 2008 by `TwoLineListItem` even though it is not used that way today. The only place where I see that layout being used today is by the Browser app.